# How to call an Express function in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Here is my express endpoint, which is meant to be called via a [webhook from Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/integration-builder):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = require('express')();
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.test.secret);
const endpointSecret = functions.config().stripe.test.webhookkey;

app.post('/stripe_webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), async (request, response) => {
    const event = request.body;
    // Only verify the event if you have an endpoint secret defined.
    // Otherwise use the basic event deserialized with JSON.parse
    if (endpointSecret) {
    // Get the signature sent by Stripe
    const signature = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
    try {
      const eventConstruct = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        request.body,
        signature,
        endpointSecret
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
      return response.sendStatus(400);
    }
    }
    console.log(`stripeEvent: ${event.type}`)
    // Handle the event
    const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
    if (event.type === 'payment_intent.succeeded'){
        const uid = await getCustomerUID(paymentIntent.customer)
        return actionRequest(uid, paymentIntent.client_secret)
    } 
  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.send();
});
```

I want to add the URL for this endpoint, so my Stripe account can trigger it. However, like a regular Cloud Function, this doesn't have a URL (which is what Stripe needs to access the webhook):

[image]

Is there any way to get the URL or to call this endpoint in another way?

PS: I'm using an express function as my regular Cloud Function below was failing with the following error: `Webhook signature verification failed. No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?`
Code:

```
exports.stripeEvent = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    // Get the signature from the request header | Verify it's coming from Stripe
    let signature = request.headers["stripe-signature"];
    // Verify the request against our endpointSecret
    console.log(`signature: ${signature}`)
    console.log(`endpointSecret: ${endpointSecret}`)
    console.log(`request.rawBody: ${request.rawBody}`)
    try {
        let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, signature, endpointSecret)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
        return response.status(400).end();
    }
    const event = request.body;
    console.log(`stripeEvent: ${event.type}`)
    // Handle the event
    const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
    if (event.type === 'payment_intent.succeeded'){
        const uid = await getCustomerUID(paymentIntent.customer)
        return actionRequest(uid, paymentIntent.client_secret)
    } 
  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.json({received: true});
  return 200;
});
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You get the function URL when you deploy the function. Then just append your express app route to the end

Comment: Yeah I have done that with regular cloud functions (gotten the URL after deployment) but the same method does not work with express endpoints like shown above. I took my base function URL and added the endpoint to it: `https://us-central1-<MY_APP>.cloudfunctions.net/stripe_webhook` - but it is not being triggered from Stripe - so the URL must be wrong.

Comment: Please share the complete code. Where have you defined the "http function" ?

Comment: `const app = require('express')();` - shown at the top of the first code block  @Dharmaraj

Comment: I meant the HTTPS function sorry

Comment: In my `index.js` file. The first code block is called from `const app = require('express')();` and the second code block is called from `const functions = require('firebase-functions');` (a regular cloud function).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231847/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-zorgan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const app = require("express")();

app.get("/test", function (req, res) {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
})

app.post("/stripe-event", function (req, res) {
    //Do the processing
    return res.sendStatus(200);
})

// This is the Firebase HTTPS function
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

When you deploy the function, you can see the URL of that function "api" in the dashboard and it should look something like: `https://<region><project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/api`.

Now if you want to call the endpoint `/test` you would have to make a call to this URL: `"https://<region><project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/api/test"`

Make sure you have this line: `exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);` 
The name of your function if you use this will be "api" and then append the API endpoint from the express app to that URL.