# Stripe callback for successful payment from redirectToCheckout

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Currently have a web app hosted on github pages.

I want to use firebase functions + stripe to handle payments.

I have most things set up and now am calling the method `stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId })`

However, on a successful payment, I want to update the database but I don't see an option add a callback. It only redirects me to a success/failure page. Im thinking of maybe redirecting back to the webapp but with some queryParams. Then check if query param is there on page load, update DB. But that seems incorrect and people could just then navigate to the specific URL to be added into the database.

How do I achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ideally use [Stripe Webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks). You can create a [HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and specify it's URL for the webhook from Stripe Dashboard. So whenever an event (e.g. checkout session completed or failed) triggers the webhook, it'll send the event details to your Cloud Function and there you can update the database as required. There is no client side involved in this so risk is negligible.

Also checkout the [Firebase Stripe Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments) that might do most of the work for you.

Comment: Right after I posted the question, i found the stripe webhooks section in the docs. However, does this mean I need to set up a server? Im not sure if you can set up webhooks with cloud functions

Comment: @Syn cloud function is essentially a server that runs only when a it gets a request (like the webhook) unlike a traditional server that runs 24*7 and charges you for that. When you deploy a function you'll get an URL that you can add in Stripe webhooks. Checkout [Firebase Stripe Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments)  that'll save some time. Also checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67356752/13130697) about Stripe and CFs.

Comment: Doesnt the webhook need to be hosted by me on a server?

Comment: @Syn Cloud Functions is the server here that you don't manage yourself and hence... called serverless. You can write an app with [Express](https://expressjs.com/) for API/webhooks routing, but it's upto you where you deploy it, Cloud Functions, Virtual machines, etc...